# Ruby integer comparison gives wrong result

Tags: ruby

As I wrote the following code I was expecting the last lines to give a `false` and zero results. Can you help me understand why is this happening?

```
id=408983265
a = id.to_s.each_char.map(&:to_i)
valid_digit = a.reverse
               .drop(1)
               .map!.with_index { |x, i| x << (i + 1) }
               .sum % 11 % 10

puts "valid digit: #{valid_digit}"  # valid digit: 5
puts "last digit: #{a.pop}"         # last digit: 5

# the problem starts here
puts valid_digit != a.pop           # true ???  It should be 5!=5 -> false 
puts valid_digit - a.pop            # 3    ???  It should be zero!
```

Comment: `Array#pop` is mutative. [Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-pop) *"Removes and returns trailing elements.
When no argument is given and self is not empty, removes and returns the last element"*. It literally "pops" the last element out of the `Array`, so when you call it the first time you are removing the last element, each subsequent time you call `pop` you are again removing an element from the right hand side of the Array. e.g. `a = [1,2,3]; a.pop #=> 3; a => [1,2]; a.pop #=> 2; a #=> [1]`.

Comment: Of course. replacing all `a.pop` with `a.last` and it works.I feel like a fool now. Thanks @engineersmnky

Comment: Using `map!` in the middle of something is a bad plan. It's intended to be used on existing structures, not intermediate ones. Many of these in-place operators do not necessarily return `self`, like `String#sub!` only returns something if the operation altered the string, `nil` otherwise, which can break your chains.

Comment: The title of this question is misleading... the comparison is giving the right result but you were just confused about what you were comparing.

Comment: Note that you can replace the line defining `a` with `a = id.digits`, in which case `a.reverse` is unnecessary. See [Integer#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits).

Comment: @g_ap It is probably just me, but I do not understand the logic of what makes a digit valid. Would you mind adding a short description of what you actually try to achieve? With some example input and the expected output?

Comment: @spickermann, the whole algorithm is about validating the id. It is valid only when the math operation on the first 8 digits as described gives the value of its last digit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in comments, your issues come from using mutative methods (`#map!` and `#pop`) where you don't need them and thus causing unexpected behavior.

As a suggestion, you can simplify your code quite a bit:

```
id.to_s.each_char.map(&:to_i)
```

Is the same as writing:

```
id.digits.reverse
```

Since your next step reverses that array of digits anyway, there's no point in reversing twice.

```
valid_digit = id.digits.drop(1)
                .map.with_index { |x, i| x << (i + 1) }
                .sum % 11 % 10
```

Alternatively, if we replace `.drop(1)` with `[1..]` and use `#reduce`, the sum can be generated in a single pass.

```
valid_digit = id.digits[1..]
                .reduce([0, 1]) { |(sum, idx), x| 
                  n = x << idx
                  [sum + n, idx + 1] 
                }[0] % 11 % 10
```

Comment: or alternatively `each_with_index.sum { |x, i| x << i + 1 }`

Comment: @Stefan or `each.with_index(1).sum {|x,i| x << i}`